Is sympy's simplify to be used on unknown functions?
The following code unexpectedly simplifies f(1)=xf(0) to f(1)=0. Is it because undefined functions are not to be used without further assumptions?
Running this should not change the expression, but it gives Eq(f(1), 0).
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols("x y")
f = Function("f")
print(Eq(f(1), x * f(0)).simplify(rational=True, doit=False))


That looks like an error. The same result is obtained with no flags, just bare .simplify().

As stated below, it shouldn't be making this change, e.g. Eq(f(1),x).simplify() is unchanged. I opened issue github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/26847 for this.
